# Fastest way to create dict from a large list of Dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

i need to create a dictionary from a large list of dict, removing all the duplicate dicts

the input list is something like:

```
input = [{'id': 1, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'},{'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'}, {'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1', 'value3': 'value4'}]
```

and i want to create a dictionary like this, using "id" value as key for the new dict:

```
output = {
    1: [{'id': 1, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'}]
    2: [{'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'}, {'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1', 'value3': 'value4'}]
}
```

my first try was:

```
    output = {}
    for el in input:
        if el['id'] not in output or el not in output[el['id']]:
            output.setdefault(el['id'], []).append(el)
```

and it actually works but it's super slow, len(input) is roughly 20k/30k items

is there any other way to do this a little bit faster?

thanks!

Comment: `defaultdict` might help.

Comment: @2rs2ts you sure it would speed up?

Comment: Why are you testing if `el['id']` is not already in `output`? How are you supposed to build a list on shared `id` keys then?

Comment: In other words, *just* the `if el['id'] not in output` test is enough to eliminate any duplicates as it'll only ever allow **one** dictionary per `el['id']` value to be accepted.

Comment: @zhangxaochen it would almost certainly do so. Even changing `el['id'] not in output` to `output.get(el['id'], None)` would help, although Martijn is correct about the validity of those semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a separate `set` to track of seen dictionaries; you'll have to convert them to hashable representations first:

```
seen = set()
drepr = lambda d: tuple(sorted(d.items()))

output = {}
for el in input:
    if drepr(el) not in seen:
        output.setdefault(el['id'], []).append(el)
        seen.add(drepr(el))
```

You can speed it up a little by using a [`collections.defaultdict` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as that'll materialize lists without having to look up a method and push a stack frame to call it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

seen = set()
drepr = lambda d: tuple(sorted(d.items()))

output = defaultdict(list)

for el in input:
    if drepr(el) not in seen:
        output[el['id']].append(el)
        seen.add(drepr(el))
```

Demo:

```
>>> input = [{'id': 1, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'},{'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'}, {'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1', 'value3': 'value4'}]
>>> seen = set()
>>> drepr = lambda d: tuple(sorted(d.items()))
>>> output = {}
>>> for el in input:
...     if drepr(el) not in seen:
...         output.setdefault(el['id'], []).append(el)
...         seen.add(drepr(el))
... 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(output)
{1: [{'id': 1, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'}],
 2: [{'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'},
     {'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1', 'value3': 'value4'}]}
```

Comment: drepr = lambda d: return sorted(d.items()) this line give me a syntax error, i'm not so familiar with lambda functions :(

Comment: Yeah, the `return` didn't belong there; corrected. Both of them (oops).

Comment: @le_vine: New, improved! Now with actually tested version. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new output list with the duplicate dicts and then make each element in the new list a unique set of dicts

```
input=[{'id': 1, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'}, {'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'}, {'value3': 'value4', 'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1'}, {'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'}]

output={}
for el in input: output.setdefault(el['id'], []).append(el)
for key in output:
    output[key]=map(dict, set(tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in output[key]))

print output

[{'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1', 'value2': 'value2'}, {'value3': 'value4', 'id': 2, 'value1': 'value1'}]
```